# How should I avoid sending duplicate emails using mailgun, taskqueue and ndb?

Tags: app-engine-ndb, mailgun, task-queue

I am using the taskqueue API to send multiple emails is small groups with mailgun. My code looks more or less like this:

```py
class CpMsg(ndb.Model):
    group = ndb.KeyProperty()
    sent = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    #Other properties


def send_mail(messages):
    """Sends a request to mailgun's API"""
    # Some code
    pass


class MailTask(TaskHandler):
    def post(self):
        p_key = utils.key_from_string(self.request.get('p'))
        msgs = CpMsg.query(
            CpMsg.group==p_key,
            CpMsg.sent==False).fetch(BATCH_SIZE)

        if msgs:
            send_mail(msgs)

            for msg in msgs:
                msg.sent = True

            ndb.put_multi(msgs)

            #Call the task again in COOLDOWN seconds
```

The code above has been working fine, but according to the docs, the taskqueue API guarantees that a task is delivered ***at least*** once, so tasks should be idempotent. Now, most of the time this would be the case with the above code, since it only gets messages that have the 'sent' property equal to False. The problem is that non ancestor ndb queries are only eventually consistent, which means that if the task is executed twice in quick succession the query may return stale results and include the messages that were just sent.

I thought of including an ancestor for the messages, but since the sent emails will be in the thousands I'm worried that may mean having large entity groups, which have a limited write throughput.

Should I use an ancestor to make the queries? Or maybe there is a way to configure mailgun to avoid sending the same email twice? Should I just accept the risk that in some rare cases a few emails may be sent more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach to avoid the eventual consistency hurdle is to make the query a `keys_only` one, then iterate through the message keys to get the actual messages by key lookup (strong consistency), check if `msg.sent` is True and skip sending those messages in such case. Something along these lines:

```
    msg_keys = CpMsg.query(
        CpMsg.group==p_key,
        CpMsg.sent==False).fetch(BATCH_SIZE, keys_only=True)
    if not msg_keys:
        return

    msgs = ndb.get_multi(msg_keys)
    msgs_to_send = []

    for msg in msgs:
         if not msg.sent:
             msgs_to_send.append(msg)
    if msgs_to_send:
        send_mail(msgs_to_send)

        for msg in msgs_to_send:
            msg.sent = True

        ndb.put_multi(msgs_to_send)
```

You'd also have to make your `post` call transactional (with the `@ndb.transactional()` decorator).

This should address the duplicates caused by the query eventual consistency. However there still is room for duplicates caused by transaction retries due to datastore contention (or any other reason) - as the `send_mail()` call isn't idempotent. Sending one message at a time (maybe using the task queue) could reduce the chance of that happening. See also [GAE/P: Transaction safety with API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55885628/gae-p-transaction-safety-with-api-calls)

Comment: Thanks Dan. I don't think I can execute a non-ancestor query inside a transaction, so unless I do the query first and then pass the results as an argument, that wouldn't work. Still, there is another problem since I can only modify up to 25 entity groups inside a transaction (GAE Datastore limit), which would put a hard limit on BATCH_SIZE.

Comment: Ah, right, forgot - yes, you'd make the query first then pass the list of keys to a transactional function to lookup and check the entities.

Comment: And given the fact that I can only update 25 entities in a transaction that would introduce another problem, since I would need a lot more tasks and API calls. Perhaps the risk and consequence of this happening isn't worth this kind of change. Do you think I should make these changes to reduce this already small chance of it happening or just wait until the migration to the new Firestore is complete, which eliminates the problem?

Comment: Yes, working around the 25 entity groups per transaction can be a bit of a nuisance. Only you can evaluate the worthiness for your app case. I'm pondering the migration to the Firestore as well, but as I tend to be a bit skeptic I'll definitely do some performance testing before I commit to it as I suspect there will be a performance price to pay for those features.